# Permutations interleaved with special values

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation, python-3.6

I am having a real brain block trying to figure this out. I am trying to write a function that will return all the permutations of a list, interleaved with some number of special values.

The function signature:

```
def interleaved_permutations(values, num_special_values)
```

An example:

```
>>> interleaved_permutations([1,2,3,4], 2)
[1,x,x,2,3,4]
[1,x,2,x,3,4]
[1,x,2,3,x,4]
[1,2,x,x,3,4]
...
```

An extra requirement is that the special values can not be first or last in the list.

I know that there must be a way with some crazy itertools foo, but I have not been able to come up with anything remotely close. the closest I have gotten is just getting the permutations of the input values with `itertools.permutations`

I am hoping somebody more pythonic than me will be able to help!

Comment: so the items [1,2,3,4] are not actually permutated? do they remain always in the [1,2,3,4] order?

Comment: they are actually permutated, just enumerating enough examples show that would have been too many! Though that is actually not hard right, you just need to apply the interleaving to every permutation. It is really the interleaving that I am having issues with @_@

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use `itertools.combinations` to choose the *positions* of the special values after insertion:

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations

def interleaved(values, num_special_values):
    width = len(values) + num_special_values
    special = 'x'
    for perm in permutations(values):
        for pos in combinations(range(1, width-1), num_special_values):
            it = iter(perm)
            yield [special if i in pos else next(it)
                   for i in range(width)]
```

which gives me

```
In [31]: list(interleaved([1,2,3], 2))
Out[31]: 
[[1, 'x', 'x', 2, 3],
 [1, 'x', 2, 'x', 3],
 [1, 2, 'x', 'x', 3],
 [...]
 [3, 'x', 'x', 2, 1],
 [3, 'x', 2, 'x', 1],
 [3, 2, 'x', 'x', 1]]
```

and

```
In [32]: list(interleaved([1,2,3,4], 2))
Out[32]: 
[[1, 'x', 'x', 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 'x', 2, 'x', 3, 4],
 [1, 'x', 2, 3, 'x', 4],
 [...]
 [4, 3, 'x', 2, 'x', 1],
 [4, 3, 2, 'x', 'x', 1]]
```

Comment: This is exactly it. I was trying to mess around with zip() and chain() to do some crazy stuff. Thank you so much. I knew I should not have started this on a Friday after sprint planning!

Answer (score 0):

Just filter out the bad permutations from the list of permutations:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> s = ['x', 'y']
>>> def good(x):
...     return x[0] not in s and x[-1] not in s
...
>>> print(*filter(good, permutations(l+s)), sep='\n')
(1, 2, 3, 'x', 'y', 4)
(1, 2, 3, 'y', 'x', 4)
(1, 2, 4, 'x', 'y', 3)
(1, 2, 4, 'y', 'x', 3)
(1, 2, 'x', 3, 'y', 4)
(1, 2, 'x', 4, 'y', 3)
(1, 2, 'x', 'y', 3, 4)
(1, 2, 'x', 'y', 4, 3)
(1, 2, 'y', 3, 'x', 4)
(1, 2, 'y', 4, 'x', 3)
(1, 2, 'y', 'x', 3, 4)
(1, 2, 'y', 'x', 4, 3)
...
(4, 'y', 'x', 2, 3, 1)
(4, 'y', 'x', 3, 1, 2)
(4, 'y', 'x', 3, 2, 1)
>>>
```